# Chudnovsky algorithm and Pi precision

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory, notation, irrational-numbers

What are the precision/ number of correct [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) digits after N iterations of [Chudnovsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm). Looking for a formula (rather than a table) and reference.

Comment: Chudnovsky's algorithm produces 14.18 digits of $\pi$ per iteration.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Is this 14.18 number known to have a closed form?

Comment: @Wojowu --- I think it does, see below.

Answer (score 6):

*[I'm following up on my comment, in response to Wojowu's query:]*

The number of digits $d$ of $1/\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$ produced per iteration by the [Chudnovsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm), which has a linear convergence, follows from $10^d=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|c_{k}/c_{k+1}|$, hence
$$d={}^{10}\log 151931373056000=14.1816\cdots$$

---

in connection with the unusual logarithm notation, I asked at HSM and got an [informative response](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/why-did-i-learn-to-write-the-base-of-the-logarithm-differently-from-the-rest-of): the notation from the early 19th century for the base of the logarithm by A.L. Crelle was a superscript either in front $^{b}\!\log$ or above $\overset{b}{\log}$ --- see page 107 of [A History of Mathematical Notations](https://books.google.nl/books?redir_esc=y&id=bT5suOONXlgC) (volume II).

Comment: Too bad it isn't 14.15926535... Gerhard "Strong Law For Irrational Numbers?" Paseman, 2017.02.02.

Comment: Does $^{10}\log$ mean $\log_{10}$?

Comment: Yes, is it an unconventional notation?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I've personally never seen it before.

Comment: this is curious; it may very well be a Dutch thing, at least the Dutch [Wikipedia](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritme) entry gives both alternative notations ${}^{a}\!\log$ and $\log_{a}$ for the base of the logarithm, and I definitely learned the former at school.

Comment: in this connection (superscript or subscript base notation), see also this [TeX posting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/customized-log-notation) --- it seems to be indeed peculiar for The Netherlands and its (former) colonies

Comment: Where has the number 151931373056000 come from?